# request for member 'attach' in 'ServoController', which is of non-class type 'int'

Tags: c++

I have a problem and I which I have been trying to solve for a few days now.

```
void setup()
{
     int EchoPin;
    int TrigPin;
    int ServoController;
    int ServoSignal;
    pinMode(EchoPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(TrigPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(DCIn1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(DCIn2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(DCIn3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(DCIn4, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(RED_LED, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(GREEN_LED, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(BLUE_LED, OUTPUT);
    ServoController.attach(ServoSignal);

    tooClose();
}
```

The error message is:

> error: request for member 'attach' in 'ServoController', which is of
>   non-class type 'int'
>
> exit status 1 request for member 'attach' in 'ServoController', which
>   is of non-class type 'int'

Comment: The error says it all...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this line? `ServoController.attach(ServoSignal);`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this code fragment comes from the [obstacle avoidance robot](https://gist.github.com/cuongdtnguyen/bd3a0e5c3736a42b247b) gitHub project. Even brief overview of the source shows that you are using it completely wrong. `ServoController` should have `Servo` type instead of `int`. `EchoPin` and all other variables should be initialized with correct values.